# $U^TA_1V$ is a rank-one matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

To give a little bit of context, the question I am asking is related to SVD decomposition. More specifically, we are trying to prove that the best rank one approximation for  $A_1$ is $\sigma_1 u_{1} v_{1}^{T}$

let $A_1$ be some rank one matrix.

Let $\|\|$ represent the Frobenius Norm of a matrix.

$$\|A-A_{1}\|=\|U\Sigma V^{T}-A_{1}\|= \|\Sigma -U^TA_1V\|$$

In the paper (pg 19) http://www.math.umn.edu/~lerman/math5467/svd.pdf, they let $U^TA_1V=\alpha x y^{T}$, where $\alpha$ is positive and $x$ and $y$ are both unit vectors of lengths $m$ and $n$ respectively.

My question is how do they know that $U^TA_1V$ is a rank-one matrix such that they can make that general substitution.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the [following property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) of rank and matrix multiplication:

> For any two matrices of appropriate size, the rank of the product is less than or equal to the rank of either of multiplicands: 
>   $
> \forall A  \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}, \ B  \in \mathbb R^{n\times k} \  
> \operatorname{rank}\left(AB\right)  \le 
> \min \big(\!\operatorname{rank} \left(A\right), \operatorname{rank} \left(B\right)\! \big).
> $

Recall also [Sylvester rank inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties):

> $
> \forall A  \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}, \ B  \in \mathbb R^{n\times k} \quad 
> \operatorname{rank}\left(A\right) + \operatorname{rank}\left(B\right) - n \le \operatorname{rank}\left(AB\right) . 
> $

---

Since  $A_1$ is a rank $1$ matrix, and $U, V$ are unitary  $n\times n$ matrices (i.e. of rank $n$), we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1 V\right) \le 
\min \big(\!\operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1\right),\operatorname{rank} V \big) 
= \min\Big(\!\min\big(\!\operatorname{rank}U^T,\operatorname{rank}A_1\big),n\Big).
\\
\operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1 V\right) \le  \min \Big(\!\min \big(n ,1 \big) , n\Big)  = \min \big(1, n\big) = 1.
$$
Therefore $$ 
\boxed{\ \operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1 V\right) \le 1\ } 
\label{1} \tag{*}
$$

On the other handy, by Sylvester inequality we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1 V\right) \ge 
\operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1\right) + \operatorname{rank}\left(V\right) - n 
= \operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1\right) 
\\
\operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1 V\right) \ge 
\operatorname{rank}\left(U^T\right) + \operatorname{rank}\left(A_1\right) - n = 1
$$

Thus, 
$$\boxed{\ \operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1 V\right) \ge 1\ }
\label{2} \tag{**}
$$

Combining $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$, we conclude that 
$$
\boxed{\boxed{\ \operatorname{rank}\left(U^T A_1 V\right) = 1\ }}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found this link which also answers my question, given we remember that $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847329/prove-rankap-ranka-if-p-is-an-invertible-n-%c3%97-n-matrix-and-a-is-any-m-%c3%97-n-m?rq=1