# Proving row rank equals column rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am studying Linear Algebra from the book of the same name by Larry Smith. I am confused with the way Smith proves that row rank of a matrix equals its column rank. Here are the things that he uses to prove it:

---

**Proposition.** Let $T: V \to V$ be an endomorphism of the finite dimensional vector space $V$. Then there exists bases $\{ a_1 , \ldots , a_n \}$ and $\{ b_1 , \ldots , b_n \}$ for $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
I_{k} & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} _{n\times n}$$
where $I_{k}$ is the identity matrix for some integer $k$. The integer $k$ is called the rank of the linear transformation $T$. In fact, $k= \dim \text{Im } T$.

---

**Definition.** For a matrix $M$ of size $m \times n$ , we define the *row rank* to be the maximal number of linearly independent rows of the matrix. Likewise, the *column rank* is the maximal number of linearly independent   columns.

---

Here's the way the author completes the proof.

**Corollary.** Let $M$ be a matrix of size $m \times n$. Then the row rank of $M$ equals the column rank of $M$.

Proof. Let $T : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be the linear transformation with matrix $M$ with respect to the standard bases. The columns of $M$ span $\text{Im } T$, so the number of linearly independent columns is the rank of the linear transformation $T$. The proposition implies that the rank of $T$ is also the number of linearly independent rows of $M$. $\blacksquare$

Here are the few questions that I have:

How does the proposition implies the rank of $T$ $=$ number of linearly independent rows of $M$. Is there anything I'm failing to notice? In fact, the proposition holds for endomorphisms and $T$ is not even an endomorphism. However, apparently the proposition can be easily generalized for any two vector spaces $V$ and $W$.

What follows is my attempt of proving it. I have tried using the change of basis theorem.

I generalized the above proposition and have stated it but not made an attempt to prove it here.

---

**Proposition 2.** Let $T: V \to W$ be a linear transformation from  the finite dimensional vector space $V$ into $W$. Then there exists bases $\{ a_1 , \ldots , a_n \}$ and $\{ b_1 , \ldots , b_m \}$ for $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
I_{k} & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} _{m\times n}$$
where $I_{k}$ is the identity matrix for some integer $k$. In fact, $k= \dim \text{Im } T$.

---

Here's my incomplete attempt at proving that row rank equals column rank:

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be the linear transformation with matrix $M$ with respect to the standard bases. By proposition 2, there are bases $\{ a_{1} , \ldots , a_{n} \}$ and $\{ b_{1} , \ldots , b_{m} \}$ such that the matrix of $T$ is 
$$J= \begin{bmatrix} 
I_{k} & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} _{m\times n}$$
Since $M$ and $J$ represent the same linear transformation, namely $T$, there are nonsingular matrices $P_{m \times m}$, $Q_{n \times n}$  such that $M=P^{-1}JQ$ or $PM=JQ$. I know that row rank of $M$ = row rank of $PM$ and column rank of $J$ = column rank of $JQ$ but how do I show that row rank of $M$ = column rank of $M$ = $k$?

Comment: $PMQ^{-1}=J$, Row rank of $M$ = Row rank of $J =k$ and similarly column rank of $M$ = column rank of $J =k$ .... check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847329/prove-rankap-ranka-if-p-is-an-invertible-n-%c3%97-n-matrix-and-a-is-any-m-%c3%97-n-m it might help

Comment: @FareedAF the first answer assumes what I'm trying to prove. Is there any other way around it? I'm quite stuck here

Comment: The number of independent rows in the matrix $J$ is clearly $k$, is this what your trying to proof? And also the number of independent columns (i.e. here the number of non-zero columns) in $J$ is also $k$

Comment: @FareedAF oh no. Row rank of J = column rank of J =k is evident from the matrix. I'm trying to prove that row rank of M = row rank of J and column rank of M = column rank of J. That would clearly complete the proof.

Comment: In the link that I sent in the first comment they proved that the rank of $PM$ equals the rank of $M$, and you can apply it again to get that the rank of $PMQ^{-1}$ equals the rank of $PM$. Hence, $PMQ^{-1}$ which is $J$ have the same rank as $M$. And knowing that row rank of $J$= column rank of $J$=rank  of $J$ and thats equal to  row rank of $M$= column rank of $M$=rank  of $M$. Thus, row rank of $M$= row rank of $J$ and same for the columns. And if you still want a proof for why row rank of $M$ = column rank of $M$, you can find that by searching google or even maybe the MSE